# Specifying JVM Eclipse Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I have a computer unable to install Java because I do not know the admin password. I have copied over my home folder from my other MacBook and edited the Eclipse.ini to run from there (yes that is the file location of the home folder I triple checked). What am I doing wrong?

```
-vm
/Users/3069264/Documents/JRE/Home/bin/java
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.committers.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Can you tell us what indication you have that something *is* wrong? The symptom?

Comment: What was in the error message? Try to execute "/Users/3069264/Documents/JRE/Home/bin/java -version" from a console

Comment: Are the java binary and other files inside bin folder are marked as executable? ls -la /Users/3069264/Documents/JRE/Home/bin